# AWK print header row and change field value

Tags: awk

I am trying to change the city on all records and keep the header.

What I have:

```
Name,City,State
Bob,Portland,Oregon
Sue,Portland,Oregon
David,Portland,Oregon
```

What I want:

```
Name,City,State
Bob,Bend,Oregon
Sue,Bend,Oregon
David,Bend,Oregon
```

What I have tried:

```
awk -F',' 'NR>1 $2 == "Portland" {$2 = "Bend";print}' OFS=","
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -F',' 'NR>1 && $2 == "Portland" {$2 = "Bend"} {print}' OFS="," file
Name,City,State
Bob,Bend,Oregon
Sue,Bend,Oregon
David,Bend,Oregon
```

or, using the usual awk shorthand:

```
awk -F',' 'NR>1 && $2 == "Portland" {$2 = "Bend"} 1' OFS="," file
```

Notes:

1. When you have two conditions, like `NR>1` and `$2 == "Portland"` and your want both to apply, they need to be combined with logical-and: `&&`.
2. You want all lines printed and awk does not print by default.  So, we moved the print command to a separate group so it applied to all lines.

#### Alternative: using sed

Using sed, we can get the same result:

```
$ sed 's/,Portland,/,Bend,/' file
Name,City,State
Bob,Bend,Oregon
Sue,Bend,Oregon
David,Bend,Oregon
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, greatly appreciated!